# Percentage of each record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I can get top N% of a table using

```
SELECT TOP N PERCENT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY Column
```

But my table look like this

[image]

The percentage column should have what is the percentage for each record based on frequency.

So each record percentage will be the top percentage it belongs to.

If we have 10 rows:

```
Code  freq  perc
-----------------
A3     982  10%     ----> 1st in order  ==> 1 / total number of records 10 ==> 0.1 ==> 10%
A1     825  20%     ----> 2nd in order  ==> 2 / total number of records 10 ==> 0.2 ==> 20%
A6     705  30%
A8     633  40%
A0     590  50%
A2     444  60%
A9     390  70%
A7     202  80%
A5     113  90%
A4     007  100%
```

Another example like this

```
Code  freq  perc
------------------
C4    8392  00.01     ----> 1st in order  ==> 1 / total number of records 10000 ==> 0.0001 ==> 0.01%
.
.
.
A6    3949  12.44    ----> 1244 in order  ==> 1 / total number of records 10000 ==> 0.1244 ==> 12.44%
.
.
.
Y9    2341  28.54
```

I can put the table in a loop and divide the number of the row on the total number of all rows. But I think this is not the right way to do that.

Is there a better way?

Comment: That edit makes it a lot easier to understand!

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counter for each row that increments by 1/total_row_count each time:

```
SELECT
  code,
  freq,
  100.0 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY freq DESC) / COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM
  table
```

For a 10000 row result set COUNT OVER will be 10000, and ROW NUMBER will increment from 1 to 10000 in descending order of freq (biggest freq first)

---

If you meant you want the percentage that a freq value represents of the total of all freq values:

```
SELECT
  code,
  freq,
  100.0 * freq/SUM(freq) OVER()
FROM
  table
```

---

if you want to store these values back in the table :

```
UPDATE table
SET perc = x
FROM
(
 SELECT
  code,
  freq,
  100.0 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY freq DESC) / COUNT(*) OVER() x
FROM
  table 
) s
```

But do bear in mind that storing the values in the table means that any insertion, deletion or change of freq will invalidate the meaning of the column. If changes are infrequent you'll can recalculate. If changes are often it might be better to just calculate the perc every tine you want it. Choose the route that calculates perc less often

Comment: the 1st query will do it, but it wont update the table? how can i put row_number in update statement?

Comment: Oh, the question didn't ask for an update.. I'll make an edit

Answer (score 1):

Although I would tend to use `row_number()` or `rank()` for this purpose (the latter handles ties), it is worth pointing out that the built-in function [`percent_rank()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select t.*, 100 * percent_rank() over (order by column) as ranking
from t;
```